# Is there a string manipulation difference between Emacs 24 and 25.1?

Tags: string

I'm test-driving Emacs 25.1 and have noticed that a simple `concat` command, which used to work in v.24 (and v.23), doesn't work in v.25.1:

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs (concat user-emacs-directory "snippets"))
```

In v.25.1 I get the following error message:

```
byte-code: Wrong type argument: listp, "~/Dropbox/emacs/snippets"
```

To make it work in v.25.1, I need to do call the function thus:

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs (concat user-emacs-directory '("snippets")))
```

So my question is, why doesn't the latter work in Emacs 25.1 anymore? (Or alternatively, is the former the *correct* way actually?)

Comment: It should be a list, instead of a string:  `(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets"))`

Comment: Yep. But notice I'm concatenating my emacs dir (in the variable `user-emacs-directory`) with the string "snippets". (I use the same config in different machines with different OSs, so I need to have different dirs in that variable.)

Comment: `(cond ((eq system-type 'darwin) (setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets"))) ((eq system-type 'windows-nt) (setq yas-snippet-dirs '("c:/emacs/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets"))))`  And you can even get specific as to what version of Windows if you use different ones -- e.g., `(and (eq system-type 'windows-nt) (equal (w32-version) '(5 1 2600)))`  You can also populate `yas-snippet-dirs` with more than one path -- it is a list -- so just add more `(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-0.8.0/snippets" "/my/path"))`

Comment: Thanks. I already had that. That's how I get to the value of `user-emacs-directory`. My problem is with the concatenation.

Comment: Can you `toggle-debug-on-error` and post the backtrace? I think the error is not triggered by the concatenation at all (and the difference is more likey due to change in yasnippet version than Emacs). By the way, the correct way should be `(setq yas-snippet-dirs (list (concat user-emacs-directory "snippets"))`

Comment: Re. building paths: consider using [`expand-file-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#index-expand_002dfile_002dname) instead of `concat`.

Comment: @npostavs Here is the log for the error: http://pastebin.com/0rtzQT6i

Comment: @npostavs Your snippet triggers an error (even when fixing the brackets).

Comment: @Constantine Thanks. This helped: `yas-snippet-dirs (list (expand-file-name "snippets" user-emacs-directory))`.

Comment: @Constantine However, my initial query remains unsolved. Why did one it work in v.24 and not in v.25.1?

Comment: Well, that backtrace confirms that it's not `concat` itself throwing the error, but it's hard to make sense of it due to byte-compilation. Can you load `yasnippet.el` without the elc and redo it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change is not in `concat`, but in `yas-snippet-dirs`. In earlier versions, `yas-snippet-dirs` could be either a single directory (a string) or a list of directories. The line

> ```
> (setq yas-snippet-dirs (concat user-emacs-directory "snippets"))
> ```

is working, it's setting `yas-snippet-dirs` to the string `"~/Dropbox/emacs/snippets"`. The error message

> ```
> byte-code: Wrong type argument: listp, "~/Dropbox/emacs/snippets"
> ```

lists that string, and is telling you that this string was used in a context that requires a list.

I'm actually surprised that your second attempt got anywhere, as Emacs from git, just like previous released versions, do not accept a list of strings as the argument of `concat`.

In any case, unless you need to keep supporting older versions of yasnippet, make `yas-snippet-dirs` a list.

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs (list (concat user-emacs-directory "snippets")))
```

or the more explicit (and theoretically more portable, and more robust as it doesn't require that `user-emacs-directory` have a trailing slash)

```
(setq yas-snippet-dirs (list (expand-file-name "snippets" user-emacs-directory)))
```

Comment: FWIW, that doesn't sound like a great library change. I wonder if the incompatibility was really necessary. Seems like the author of ya-snippet might have respected backward compatibility a bit better. (Typically code just creates a singleton list if the thing in question is a non-nil atom.)

Comment: @Drew I only skimmed the code in git. The documentation no longer says that strings are accepted, but some of the code still accepts strings. The lack of support for strings may be unintended and may only arise in specific use cases.

Comment: "Emacs [...] do[es] not accept a list of strings as the argument of `concat`." - the arguments to `concat` are `user-emacs-directory` and `"snippets"`, both of which are strings, not lists.

Comment: @npostavs I was refering to the “I need to do call the function thus” bit. I've clarified my answer.